# Ошибка при получении часов и минут из Date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ошибка: `TypeError: props.date.getHours is not a function`

При создании нового поста добавляю ему время через `new Date()`:

```js
await userSchema.updateOne({
  email: findUser.email,
  password: findUser.password,
}, { $push: { posts: { $each: [{ text: message, time: new Date() }], $position: 0 } } });
```

Получаю посты пользователя и передаю всю инфу в компонент `<Post/>`:

```js
{user.posts && user.posts.map((post, index) => {
  return (
    <Post
      key={index}
      photo={user.photo}
      name={user.name}
      text={post.text}
      date={post.time}
      likes={0}
      comments={0}
      nameLink={true}
      userId={user._id}
    />
   )
})}
```

После чего вывожу время, но вылазит ошибка:

```html
<span className="post-date">
  {props.date.getHours() + ":" + props.date.getMinutes()}
</span>
```

Я так понимаю, что временем является строка или что?

Comment: new Date(props.date).getHours()

Comment: сработало, спасибо

Comment: наверное, лучше таймстемп хранить в пропсах